# Rename django custom permissions

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations, django-permissions

I'm working with django 2.0 app and going to update django version to 3.0. 
But in my project there are few custom permissions named like **view_modelname**.

```
class MyConcreteModel(models.Model):
    model_field_1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    # other fields
    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ("view_myconcretemodel", "Can see available device interfaces"),
        )
```

In django 3 (since v 2.1) such kind of permissions are default. So I got conflict with permission names.

Now I'm trying to rename custom permissions before updating django version.

```
class MyConcreteModel(models.Model):
    model_field_1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    # other fields
    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ("user_view_myconcretemodel", "User can see available device interfaces"),
        )
```

After migration 'new' (with new names) permissions were created in DB. But old permissions still there and all users have old permissions (with old names like **view_myconcretemodel**). Obviously I need 'new' permissions for all users.

Is there possibility simple to rename permissions or give 'new' permissions to relevant users (according to 'old' permissions), and do it automatically?

Answer (score 2):

After reading how to Programmatically creating permissions https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#programmatically-creating-permissions

My solution is to modify `codename` in `Permission` model. i.e.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission

perm = Permission.objects.get(codename="view_myconcretemodel") #old name
perm.codename = "user_view_myconcretemodel" #new name
perm.save()
```

Comment: I did this in a migration:
  `def update_permission_name(apps, schema_editor):
    Permission = apps.get_model("auth", "Permission")
    perm = Permission.objects.get(codename="oldname",content_type_id=ID)
    perm.codename = "newname" # or you can also set a new name here
    perm.save()`

Worked like a charm ;)